# Working on a MS Access file with ODBC connection on OSX

Tags: macos, ms-office, database

I need to open an `accdb` file on my MacBook Pro (OSX 10.8.5). This file uses an `ODBC` data source connection. So I guess my questions are:

1. How do I setup a new ODBC data source connection on a Mac?
2. What app I could use to open the `accdb` file, with data source connection support?

**Update:
This is how my User DNS connection looks like on my Windows PC**

I think the data source might actually be a SQL Server

[image]

Comment: I think that there is more than ODBC needed, an ODBC connector can be found , however I don't think you can open an access file as that requires an access database engine running on the client. If the database was Sql Server then it is possible to use ODBC on OSX to connect to it.

Comment: The data source connection is actually setup as a SQL Server. Here's a screenshot of how my User DNS configuration looks like on Windows: http://i.imgur.com/hk5vdTU.png

Comment: Which data source do you use as you have to use one of them and if it is SQL server then there is no Access DB